# Not getting album ids from Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not getting anything here. Am I doing something wrong? I can fetch other data like picture, etc, so I know the call to the FB server is working

```js
FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id', function(response) {
  var r = response;
});
```

[image]

I also tried

> 'me?fields=albums.fields(id,name,cover_photo,photos.fields(name,picture,source))'

with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't request the `user_photos` permission. Without it, you'll not be able to retrieve the album data.